# Docusign not showing recipientview on Embedded signing instead shows Admin View

Tags: jwt, docusignapi, envelope

I am going on rounds for the past 4 days with this problem and unable to figure out why.
.Using Python and JWT Auth , when a user logs into our app they need to add some fields and that data needs to be filled in the Docusign template for the user to sign. Here the impersonation is not working . Every time I open the Docusign file it opens it on my creds - Admin Mode( I got consent as an admin).Not as the signer specified like below. Can someone help ?

```
apiClient = DsClient.update_token()

apiClient.host = "https://na3.docusign.net" + "/restapi"     

   with open(path.join( '/app/templates/', 'sasa.pdf'), "rb") as file:
        content_bytes = file.read()
   base64_file_content = base64.b64encode(content_bytes).decode('ascii')

    # Create the document model
   document = Document( 
        document_base64 = base64_file_content,
        name = 'Example document', 
        file_extension = 'pdf', 
        document_id = 1 
    )
   signer = Signer( 
        email = 'xzr@gmail.com', name = 'abc',
        recipient_id = "1", routing_order = "1",
        client_user_id = '123',
        role_name = 'Signer'
    )
   
   
   sign_here = SignHere(  
            anchor_string="/sn1/", anchor_units="pixels",
            anchor_y_offset="10", anchor_x_offset="20"
        )


   signer.tabs = Tabs(sign_here_tabs = [sign_here])
  
   
   envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
    email_subject = "Please sign this document sent from the Python SDK",
    documents = [document],
    recipients = recipients.Recipients(signers = [signer]),
    status="sent"
    )

   envelope_api = EnvelopesApi(apiClient)
   
   results = envelope_api.create_envelope(session['account_id'], envelope_definition=envelope_definition)
   envelope_id = results.envelope_id
   
   recipient_view_request = RecipientViewRequest(
            authentication_method='None',
            client_user_id='123',  
            return_url="http://localhost:3000/",
            user_name='xyz', 
            email="xzr@gmail.com
            
        )
  
   results = envelope_api.create_recipient_view(account_id=session['account_id'],envelope_id=envelope_id,recipient_view_request=recipient_view_request)  
   return jsonify({"envelope_id": envelope_id,'redirect_url': results.url})
```

***CREATE RECIPIENT VIEW***

```
POST https://na3.docusign.net:8832/restapi/v2.1/accounts/f9bbb4d1-b163-40b9-9f24-8473123310dd/envelopes/dfa2eb5c-db75-45b3-b1b8-941c09750c01/views/recipient
Content-Length: 151
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: identity
Authorization: Bearer [omitted]
Host: na3.docusign.net
User-Agent: Swagger-Codegen/v2.1/3.9.0rc1/python3
X-DocuSign-SDK: Python
X-Forwarded-For: 107.129.120.208
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

{
    "authenticationMethod": "None", 
    "clientUserId": "123", "email": "xyz@gmail.com", 
    "returnUrl": "http://localhost:3000/", "userName": "Shilpa"
}

201 Created

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1466
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: eccb191e-e3f3-4cba-9f30-59f85dce54c5

{"url":"https://na3.docusign.net/Signing/MTRedeem/v1/eccb191e-e3f3-4cba-9f30-59f85dce54c5/na?29yaXRobSI6MCwiSGFzaFJvdW5....tw"}
```

Comment: Please use DocuSign's [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to obtain the API logs for your Envelopes:create and Recipient View API calls. Then add the logs to your question by **editing** your question.

Comment: @LarryK - pasted the request recipient. Have loads of logs unsure which one you can help trouble shoot

Comment: Please provide the create envelope log too. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there were multiple anchor_string="/sn1/" in the document so it kept failing to add a signature tab which lead to the admin view. Docusign support was able to resolve it for me .Thanks .

It would have been really nice if it was able to throw an error for it , instead it simply opened it in Admin or a view where user was able to do anything on the form.

Comment: Thanks for this, it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `templateId`, so you're not creating your envelope from template?

However, you have a role element in the singer here:

```
role_name = 'Signer'
```

Try to remove above line and see if that resolve this.

Another potential thing to try is to open an incognito window for your recipient to sign and not use the same browser that has a cookie logging you to the admin.

Comment: I have already tried that , didn't work . Template is created from the document . But even if I already have a template it still doesn't impersonate. The only thing that is left is we have our account authentication by SSO .Does that have any impact on this ?

Comment: I see this is in production, not in the developer account. Did this app already go-live? did it work ok in the developer env? or is this a regression?

Comment: it is the same problem in dev environment as well as PRD . All the requests show 200 but the doc opens as an admin with access to edit everything on the document and also shows my name (I am the admin). We went to PRD docusign account thinking this probably is a feature available only in PRD.I have read every single document of yours and examples but except the SSO auth that I said above I don't see any other descrepanices.

Comment: create a new developer account, without SSO, try it and see if that's the root cause.

Comment: SSO meaning - My admin account access is only via SSO

Comment: I am doing that ,meanwhile do you see anything in the code that can be wrong ?

Comment: Is this Python? Node? you can try our quickstart and see if that works

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/

Comment: trying Quickstart now. MySure app is exactly similar to our arch .React and Python

Comment: You can also try MySure code if you want, I was trying something even simpler to get this working

Comment: QuickStart is not installing correctly showing some dependency errors

Comment: well are you using the DocuSign.eSign package?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/docusign-esign/

Comment: The quick start example worked ! But it has both Auth grant and JWT .Will try to look and replicate the steps on my app.Still have no clue how that worked.

Comment: Not sure your issue is related to JWT/Auth Code Grant. Doesn't seem about authentication

Comment: I take my comment back , the example didn't work on inconginto mode , so it was asking me to login even though I had a JWT auth set up . So is there a compulsion for every user to login when they have to add a signature on the app ?